# Could not complete cursor operation because the set options have changed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @dbname VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR
  SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE version != 0

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

  --SELECT 'IF (@dbname = ''' + name + ''') USE ' + name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE version != 0 AND name NOT IN ('msdb', 'master', 'tempdb', 'model')
  IF (@dbname = 'A') USE A
  IF (@dbname = 'B') USE B
  IF (@dbname = 'C') USE C
  IF (@dbname = 'D') USE D
  IF (@dbname = 'E') USE E
  IF (@dbname = 'F') USE F
  IF (@dbname = 'G') USE G
  IF (@dbname = 'H') USE H
  IF (@dbname = 'I') USE I

  FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname
END

CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

I got the following error

> Could not complete cursor operation because the set options have
>   changed

What is a problem?

Comment: That works for me - so long as I change A-I to be my actual database names. What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @Dale Burrell I use 'Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP4-GDR) (KB4057114) - 10.0.6556.0 (X64)   Dec 28 2017 15:21:01   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0 <X64> (Build 6002: Service Pack 2) (VM) '

Comment: Almost certainly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your script does nothing - but it most likely will attempt to do something eventually. What are you trying to accomplish? Your path will lead to many problems if you intend to dynamically change the current database during execution since the script is compiled once and all references in it will be resolved to the current database at the time of compilation.

Comment: @SMor the docs say that `use` is effective at runtime as well as compile time, and it works for 2012 as written. However I agree its probably XY - it doesn't sound like a good approach.

Comment: The error says what the issue is. (At least) one of the databases you're using has (at least) one conflicting setting. From a quick test of my own, changing the `numeric_roundabort` setting on a database seems to produce the same error. I'm not sure if any other settings would also produce the error in this instance (where you aren't really doing anything except checking whether @@fetch_status = 0) but it would depend on what you're doing after you change databases in the cursor, I suppose.

Comment: I want to get all object privileges for all databases from all users. So I tried `fetch @@dbname @sql='use ' + @@dbname exec(@sql) something doing what i want next @@dbname ..` at first time.  But it was not working. So I have adopted the content of the text(
Although it is an ignorant way). And I got the error.

Comment: One more thing. I changed the query to `use ?` from `FETCH INTO @@dbname   
 & if (.. ) use ` This works for all databases. 
Well... I don't know what the internal processing is.

Comment: @DaleBurrell You miss the point. The batch is compiled once. The script, as posted, does nothing useful. Once the "useful" code is added, things will go south very quickly. This is almost certainly a case where dynamic sql will be required.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to simulate your problem.

Changing Database may cause an error but I've tried to use `exec` and changed `A` to `master`

like this:

```
  GO
Create procedure proc_UseDatabase as 
begin
declare @DB as varchar(max)
DECLARE @dbname VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT name FROM  master.[dbo].sysdatabases WHERE version != 0

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

  --SELECT 'IF (@dbname = ''' + name + ''') USE ' + name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE version != 0 AND name NOT IN ('msdb', 'master', 'tempdb', 'model')
  IF (@dbname = 'master')
  set @DB = 'USE master'
  exec(@DB)

   IF (@dbname = 'B')
  set @DB = 'USE B'
  exec(@DB)
   IF (@dbname = 'C')
  set @DB = 'USE C'
  exec(@DB)
   IF (@dbname = 'D')
  set @DB = 'USE D'
  exec(@DB)
   IF (@dbname = 'E')
  set @DB = 'USE E'
  exec(@DB)
   IF (@dbname = 'F')
  set @DB = 'USE F'
  exec(@DB)
   IF (@dbname = 'G')
  set @DB = 'USE G'
  exec(@DB)
   IF (@dbname = 'H')
  set @DB = 'USE H'
  exec(@DB)
   IF (@dbname = 'I')
  set @DB = 'USE I'
  exec(@DB)

 set @DB = @DB
  FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname
END
select @DB  -- Just get the return value of 'exec' to view a result
CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
end
GO
```

There's no error return:

You can simulate also using this.

Hope it helps

Comment: My query was very long so I couldn't input the query in all exec(..). I changed the query to 'use ?'.  Anyway Thank you for answering. I hope you have a good day.